# covariance of two ito integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t=\int_0^t \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u$. Assume $0\lt s \lt t\lt T$. Is the following the right way to compute the covariation of $X_s$ and $X_t$?

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X_t, X_s) &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left( X_t - \mathbb{E}[X_t] \right)\left( X_s - \mathbb{E}[X_s] \right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[X_t X_s]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\int_0^s \left(\frac{1-s}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\int_s^t \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u+\int_0^s \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\right)\int_0^s \left(\frac{1-s}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^s \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\int_0^s \left(\frac{1-s}{1-u}\right)^k dW_u\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^s \left(\frac{1-t}{1-u}\right)^k\left( \frac{1-s}{1-u}\right)^k du\right]\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For a straightforward approach, write $X_t$ and $X_s$ as stochastic integrals on $(0,T)$ and apply the general formula.

Comment: do you mean something like $X_t=\int_0^T f(t).\mathbb{1}_{s<t}dW_s$?

Comment: Indeed, but this can onnly be done if $f(t)\mathbf 1_{s<t}$ in your comment is actually some $f(t,s)\mathbf 1_{s<t}$ hence the covariance of $X_t$ and $X_s$ is *by definition* $$\int_0^T(f(t,u)\mathbf 1_{u<t})\cdot(f(s,u)\mathbf 1_{u<s})\cdot du=\cdots$$